# How to reach additional containers by the hostname after docker-compose scale?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using the docker-compose 1.6 with docker 1.10.1 and version 2 of docker-compose.yml.

As described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), new network is created and all containers are assigned hostnames in it after `docker-compose up`.

How can I reach additional (i.e. scaled) containers via hostnames after `docker-compose scale <component>=2`?

Comment: Answered at http://stackoverflow.com/a/39895650/3423324

Answer (score 9):

When using "scale", internal docker dns service resolves only full names like projectname_db_1, projectname_db_2 and so on. Certainly, it would be better to provide in addition resolving service name + index without project name prefix.

Comment: This worked for me as of docker-compose version 1.17.1

Answer (score 6):

Based on examples I've seen, assuming your container name is `db`, the scaled containers have the names of `db_1`, `db_2`, etc...

Comment: How would that work with a tool like nginx where the config is predefined? Would I have to use Docker events to scan for new hosts and update the list of backends? (similar to how interlock works)

Comment: I've tried to use container names, but it seems that they are not populated to DNS

Comment: @tpbowden One way would be to edit the nginx config and restart nginx after adding additional containers.  Auto-scaling of the load balancer is possible with projects like https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-haproxy, but it seems like these work by bind-mounting the docker daemon socket into the container.

Answer (score 2):

I have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39895650/3423324) that question based on python with the docker api.

You basically can use the `docker api`, to figure out what your project name and service name is.

Then you can filter all available containers for the same `project`+`service` to get other instances of yourself.

With the lookup of the numbers you can finally construct the hostnames.

See **[How to get infos about ourself in a compose cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770712/how-to-get-infos-about-ourself-in-a-compose-cluster)**
[(backup at gist.github.com)](https://gist.github.com/luckydonald/8e13eae89925b79ba4cce3ece9fb1955)

Answer (score 0):

Each container is registered on network with the service name, so you don't need to know the actual container name as `service_x` but can directly use `service`.

When a service is scaled to X replica, DNS query will return multiple results:

```
/ # nslookup test
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11:53

Non-authoritative answer:

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   test
Address: 172.19.0.4
Name:   test
Address: 172.19.0.2
Name:   test
Address: 172.19.0.5
Name:   test
Address: 172.19.0.3
```

Application code can then rely on this to select a replica to connect to, or you can setup a proxy to offer some load-balancing