# How can a container identify which container it is in a set of a scaled docker-compose service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I have a docker container called `node` that I want to scale to n containers.
A given `node` container needs to know which container it is in the set of n scaled `node` containers.
The total could be in an environment variable, but the current is more troubling.

```
$ docker-compose scale node=100

Starting projectdir_node_1 ... done
Creating and starting projectdir_node_2 ... done
Creating and starting projectdir_node_3 ... done
Creating and starting projectdir_node_4 ... done
Creating and starting projectdir_node_5 ... done
Creating and starting projectdir_node_6 ... done
Creating and starting projectdir_node_7 ... done
Creating and starting projectdir_node_8 ... done
Creating and starting projectdir_node_9 ... done
...
Creating and starting projectdir_node_99 ... done
Creating and starting projectdir_node_100 ... done
```

How can `projectdir_node_100` know it is node `100`?
I saw that `$HOSTNAME` is the container id (e.g. `2c73136347cd`), but found no ENV variable for the hostname with number I need.

For reference, my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  node:
    build: ./node/
    volumes:
      - ./node/code/:/code:ro
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash"]
```

I found the unsolved [How to reach additional containers by the hostname after docker-compose scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031176/how-to-reach-additional-containers-by-the-hostname-after-docker-compose-scale), but I still don't know which container I am.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be solved by using the Docker api.

While the code in this answer is Python, and my linked example is Java, this is pretty independent of your language. Just use the Docker API with a library of your choice, or make requests directly to the Docker API socket.

I used the [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) package to access it.

The api exposes a `labels` dictionary for each container, and the keys `com.docker.compose.container-number`, `com.docker.compose.project` and `com.docker.compose.service` did what was needed to build the **hostname**.

The code below is a simplified for code I am now using.
You can find my advanced code with caching and fancy stuff that at Github at [luckydonald/pbft/dockerus.ServiceInfos (python)](https://github.com/luckydonald/pbft/blob/14cb322b1ef804dcfe3cf77e24654f5351c93edc/code/dockerus.py) as well as a similar java version at [luckydonald/pbft-java/de.luckydonald.utils.dockerus.Dockerus (java)](https://github.com/luckydonald/PBFT-JAVA/blob/de3d1d5c1183b949cf690be11f2bdac966ea7dfd/src/main/java/de/luckydonald/utils/dockerus/Dockerus.java#L17) which tries to do the same thing in java, but is probably harder to read, and has no caching.

something

Lets tackle this in steps:

---

**0. Make the API available to the container.**

We need to make the socket file available to the volume, so in the volume section of your `docker-compose.yml` file add `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  node:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

This maps the socket file into the docker container.
Because we don't expose any socket ports, we don't have to worry about firewalls for the outside world.

---

**1. Connect to the API**

Now we can connect to it. As I am using python, I use [docker-py](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) for that.

```py
from docker import Client  # pip install docker-py

cli = Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
```

---

**2. Getting all containers in the same scale group, by filtering the containers by our own project name and service name.**

###### Find ourself

To know which container we are, we compare the `$HOSTNAME` environment variable with the container `Id`.

```py
import os
HOSTNAME = os.environ.get("HOSTNAME")

all_containers = cli.containers()

# filter out ourself by HOSTNAME
our_container = [c for c in all_containers if c['Id'][:12] == HOSTNAME[:12]][0]
```

The hostname should be 12 characters of the `Id`, so we cut the id when comparing to be sure it will be equal.
`our_container` now is the api representation of ourself. Yay.

###### Next is to get the other containers.

We will search for containers which have the same project and service names.
That way we know they are instances of ourself.

```py
service_name = our_container.Labels['com.docker.compose.service']
project_name = our_container.Labels['com.docker.compose.project']

filters = [
  'com.docker.compose.project={}'.format(project_name),
  'com.docker.compose.service={}'.format(service_name)
]
# The python wrapper has a filter function to do that work for us.
containers = cli.containers(filters={'label': filters})
```

We only want each container where the `com.docker.compose.project` and `com.docker.compose.service` label is the same as our own container's.

###### And finally build a list of hostnames

```py
hostname_list = list()
for container in containers:
  project = container.Labels["com.docker.compose.project"]
  service = container.Labels["com.docker.compose.service"]
  number  = container.Labels["com.docker.compose.container-number"]
  hostname = "{project}_{service}_{i}".format(project=project, service=service, i=number)
  hostname_list.append(hostname)
# end for
```

So, we got our `hostname_list`.

I am also using that as a class, with caching the values for a minute:
[dockerus.ServiceInfos](https://github.com/luckydonald/pbft/blob/14cb322b1ef804dcfe3cf77e24654f5351c93edc/code/dockerus.py) (backup at [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/luckydonald/8e13eae89925b79ba4cce3ece9fb1955))

Comment: Backup of this answer and the code file at [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/luckydonald/8e13eae89925b79ba4cce3ece9fb1955)

Answer (score -3):

The latest version of docker should be able to autodiscover scaled services. For example:

```
services:
  app: {}
  worker: {}
```

Run scale after booting up your docker-compose:

```
docker-compose scale worker=10
```

Your app container can call the services via:

```
http://worker{:port}
```

Docker will pick a random running worker container to forward the request to.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. Here it is asked how a service, here for example `worker8` can know that it is number `8` of `10` of those scaled services.

Comment: Apologies, I was assuming you needed to communicate w/ other containers after you scaled. I'm curious, why do you need to know the container's number?

Comment: A cluster of nodes had to communicate which each other, in a Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerant Algorithm (https://github.com/luckydonald/pbft) where multiple clients have to agree on one sensory value.
With the docker `scale` command that can easily be tested with as many clients as wanted. However, those need to communicate with other clients directly, not with some (round robin) "randomly" selected node.